# Classical VAE not learning 2D gaussian mixture distribution using MSE loss

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, autoencoders, variational-bayes, generative-models

I've been exploring VAE for non-image data. I consider small to medium-sized continuous vector spaces and I want to learn the distribution of a dataset in that space.
As a warm up exercise, I tried the dummy case of learning a 2d Gaussian Mixture distribution, naïvely thinking this would be a piece of cake for the VAE.

### Summary :

I need to use a `tfp.layers.MixtureNormal` as decoder output because the classical VAE only generates centroids (and edges linking them). Is it expected? Or is it due to a bad network architecture and/or layer activation? (i've been using Dense layers, mixing tanh and linear, and MSE reconstruction loss)

### Details:

I posting because I am puzzled by the results (obviously). First, I try a relatively shallow vanilla VAE with MSE reconstruction error, I see three issues

- the distribution latent space is very much structured like the input distribution, if shomehow crammed into the target N(0,1). Adding depth or width doesn't seem to help.
- The generation process is focussed on the Gaussians centroids, and their widths is essentially not represented. It seems it's not even trying to get the covariance of the normal. Adding depth or width doesn't seem to help, it just reduces the accumulations in virtual modes (not in input)
- The "gaps" in the latent space cause significant generated data to essentially create edges between the mode centroids.

Some figures below might make my points clearer.

I tried to use a multi-modal, probabilistic decoder output (`tfp.layers.MixtureNormal`) and get much better results, but not consistently. Overall, it helps if I pack enough components that at least one ends up on each mode. But I can easily end up with some of my input component being covered by a single ouput component (which is not good). On the plus side, the latent space is very smooth. This is very good for generation, but I fear that it means my reconstruction is a bit too random between modes.

There are many configurations in which things get a bit hairy, but it seems the probabilistic decoder is helping a ton ( at the cost of needing more parameters), while the classical decoder just cannot get the job done.
Is it expected? Am I missing something obvious? I know VAE are supposed to be blurrier but here it seems it's more like it collapses.
Any comment?
I add the code below

note (edit): I now tried many other things but very few can fit the distribution at all, and even fewer without encoder collapse (regularization must be tuned down).

### Code :

versions :

```
tensorflow==2.9.1
tensorflow-probability==0.16.0
```

imports :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import torch

import tensorflow as tf
tfk = tf.keras
tfkl = tfk.layers
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfpl = tfp.layers
tfd = tfp.distributions
```

Model :

```
class EmbeddingGenerator():
    def __init__(self, dimension, probabilistic_multi_modal_output, num_components):
        self.probabilistic_multi_modal_output = probabilistic_multi_modal_output
        
        # layers size
        self.input_dim = dimension
        self.hidden_dim = dimension*num_components
        self.latent_dim = dimension
        self.output_dim = dimension

        # number of components to fit
        self.num_components = num_components

        # build encoder
        self.prior = tfd.Independent(tfd.Normal(loc=tf.zeros(self.latent_dim), scale=1), reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1)
        self.encoder = tfk.Sequential([
            tfkl.InputLayer(input_shape=self.input_dim),
            tfkl.Dense(self.hidden_dim, activation='linear'),
            tfkl.Dense(self.hidden_dim, activation='tanh'),
            tfkl.Dense(tfpl.IndependentNormal.params_size((self.latent_dim,)), activation='linear', use_bias=True),
            tfpl.IndependentNormal(self.latent_dim, activity_regularizer=tfpl.KLDivergenceRegularizer(self.prior))
        ])

        # build decoder
        self.decoder = tfk.Sequential([
            tfkl.InputLayer(input_shape=[self.latent_dim]),
            tfkl.Dense(self.hidden_dim, activation='linear'),
            tfkl.Dense(self.hidden_dim, activation='tanh'),
        ])

        # build last layer and loss depending on whether decoder has a deterministic
        # or probabilistic output
        if probabilistic_multi_modal_output:
            output_layer = tfp.layers.MixtureNormal(self.num_components, event_shape=(self.output_dim,))
            param_size = tfpl.MixtureNormal.params_size(self.num_components, (self.output_dim,))
            self.decoder.add(tfkl.Dense(param_size, activation='linear'))
            self.decoder.add(output_layer)
            self.loss = lambda x, x_hat : -x_hat.log_prob(x)
        else:
            self.decoder.add(tfkl.Dense(self.output_dim, activation='linear'))
            self.loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

        # Build full network
        self.net = tfk.Model(
            inputs=self.encoder.inputs,
            outputs=self.decoder(self.encoder.outputs[0])
        )
        self.optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
        self.net.compile(optimizer=self.optimizer, loss=self.loss)

        self.encoder.summary()
        self.decoder.summary()

    def sample(self, n):
        z = self.prior.sample(n)
        if self.probabilistic_multi_modal_output:
            out=self.decoder(z).sample()
        else:
            out=self.decoder(z)
        return out
```

Data generation :

```
n = 100000
ncom_real = 4
dimension = 2
train_dist = tfd.MixtureSameFamily(
    mixture_distribution=tfd.Categorical(probs=[1]*(ncom_real)), #np.random.rand(ncom_real)
    components_distribution=tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(
        loc=[[1,3],[5,-7],[-3,1],[-7,-5]], # [tf.zeros(dimension)-np.random.randint(low=-10, high=10, size=dimension) for _ in range(ncom_real)]
    scale_identity_multiplier=[0.5]*(ncom_real)))
train_tensor = train_dist.sample(n)
```

Training :

```
model_deter = EmbeddingGenerator(dimension=dimension, probabilistic_multi_modal_output=False, num_components=4*ncom_real)
model_deter.net.fit(train_tensor, train_tensor, epochs=10)

model_proba = EmbeddingGenerator(dimension=dimension, probabilistic_multi_modal_output=True, num_components=4*ncom_real)
model_proba.net.fit(train_tensor, train_tensor, epochs=10)
```

Sampling :

```
train_tensor = train_tensor

proba_synth_tensor = model_proba.sample(n)
deter_synth_tensor = model_deter.sample(n)

proba_encoded_tensor = model_proba.encoder(train_tensor).sample()
deter_encoded_tensor = model_deter.encoder(train_tensor).sample()
```

Viz :

```
df = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(proba_encoded_tensor.numpy()).assign(role='proba'),
    pd.DataFrame(deter_encoded_tensor.numpy()).assign(role='deter')
]).reset_index(drop=True)
sns.displot(data=df, x=0, y=1, hue='role', kind='hist', rug=True, height=10, bins=1000)
plt.show()

df = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(train_tensor.numpy()).assign(role='train'),
    pd.DataFrame(proba_synth_tensor.numpy()).assign(role='synthetic_proba'),
    pd.DataFrame(deter_synth_tensor.numpy()).assign(role='synthetic_deterministic')
]).reset_index(drop=True)
sns.displot(data=df, x=0, y=1, hue='role', kind='hist', rug=True, height=10, bins=1000)
plt.show()
```

Result with 1 linear + 1 tanh hidden layers
[image]

Result with 6 hidden layers (lin-tanh-tanh-lin-tanh-tanh), hidden width = `dimension*4*n_components`
[image]

Corresponding embedding space :
[image]

Comment: Based on the image of the embedding space it seems like there is a different degree of regularisation. Which loss function is optimised? How do you include and tune the influence of the KL divergence? It seems like the regularisation is not done sufficient and the probabilistic decoder might improve on this by ensuring a smoother structure in the embedding space.

Comment: I can see this line `tfpl.IndependentNormal(self.latent_dim, activity_regularizer=tfpl.KLDivergenceRegularizer(self.prior))` but I don't know tensorflow and whether that line is enough to make the regularisation work enough.

Comment: To my understanding, the regularization is the same between the two approahces but indeed I didn't try to adapt the weight of the KLD. The converged loss are of the same magnitude in both models though. About 4.4 for the deterministic decoder, and 2.8 for the one with GMM output layer. I will check if I can show both contributions to the loss during convergence.

Comment: After playing around a bit, it seems that increasing the weight of the KLD preserves the VAE-GMM performance (as it is virtually 0). However, for the classical VAE, the standard loss converges to about 50-50 contribution of KLD and MSE. However, increasing the KLD weight does not work. The latent space distribution remains multi-modal in a wide range of weights. Above a certain threshold, the modes collapse both in the embedding and reconstruction spaces.

Comment: After placing my comment I got the idea that regularisation isn't all of the problems. It seems that there might be more to it than just the regularization. You do not only have the additional artifacts from the "gaps" in the latent space, you also have that the model is missing the widths of the centroids. Possibly there is a problem with convergence.

Comment: TBH, that is my problem. Either an issue with convergence or with the network design. But I could not make it work. It looks like the classical model is able to fold the latent space distribution and ship it to wherever the centroids are (yielding those connecting lines between modes), but it is not able to translate and shape the whole distribution. I would expect that some network would activate different regions of the latent space and perform a simple linear transformation on each mode to get the final distribution, but it doesn't do that and I'm not sure why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136722/discussion-between-sextus-empiricus-and-wilmerton).

Comment: Are the first images the encoded results from the original data or from a new sample?

Comment: I am asking that question because I wonder whether the bad reproduction is due to a bad encoding and decoding (whether even the original sample does not match the picture), or whether it is due to irregularities and lack of smoothness in the embedding space such that small deviations (like when generating new data) are causing the problems.